# Подсчет времени, сколько человек провел в голосовом канале дискорд

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хочу реализовать функцию, при которой пользователю будет засчитываться 1 монета, за каждую минуту в голосовом канале. Правда, я не знаю, как реализовать подсчет времени в голосовом чате дискорд (любом голосовом чате).

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему, создав bot.event функцию, под названием `on_voice_state_update` , а после сделал цикл, который каждые 10 секунд, засчитывает 10 секунд пользователю.

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel!=None:
        while True:
            #здесь зачисляете секунды, а после пишите await asyncio.sleep(кол-во секунд), например a+=10 await asyncio.sleep(10) , зачисляется 10 секунд.
```

Comment: Так код привели бы. Такой ответ мало чем полезен, полагаю. Тут нет ответа на "как реализовать подсчет времени в голосовом чате дискорд"

Comment: @Сергей код я делал под себя, про зачисление секунд там мало написано.

Comment: @Сергей добавил по вашей просьбе что-то, похожее на шаблон.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня это был комментарий в рамках стандартной проверки сообщений с потенциально низким качеством. Так и дописали бы кодом. Судя по этому сайту, многие из пишущих боты  пытаются вообще не знать программирование:-) и ваш комментарий им может быть сложен.

Comment: @Сергей да я уже заметил, что когда я задаю вопрос на любую тему, то мне отвечают быстро , либо вообще отвечают, а на тему дискорд ботов не отвечают практически никогда. В любом случае, если писатели ботов, хотя бы часик помучались и полазили по сайтам американским и т.д., то точно бы поняли.